# Vanish element with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a element which is draggable. I want this element to disappear after the user moves it quickly left from right.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
});
```

The idea is to keep the element draggable, but if the user shakes it quickly (left to right or inverse), then the element disappears.

Comment: Need a lot more info, and some code of what you have already tried would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

You have to capture the Drag Event in your Draggable Window Plugin.... (if you are using one)
And just say

```
$(this).hide();
```

Comment: `.hide()` would be an unexpected result for the end-user. a `fadeTo(time,opacity)` or a `.fadeOut(time)` would be more 'understandable' Any way, I think the OP is missing how to construct the 'moving/dragging left-right'